# Create ranking based on Dates (Quarter) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

We will start with the following DataTable:

```
    id       date
 1:  1 2016-03-31
 2:  1 2015-12-31
 3:  1 2015-09-30
 4:  1 2015-06-30
 5:  1 2015-03-31
 6:  2 2016-03-31
 7:  2 2015-09-30
 8:  2 2015-06-30
 9:  2 2015-03-31
10:  2 2014-12-31

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 as.IDate(c("2016-03-31", "2015-12-31", "2015-09-30", "2015-06-30", 
                   "2015-03-31", "2016-03-31", "2015-09-30", "2015-06-30",
                   "2015-03-31", "2014-12-31")))
setnames(DT, c("id", "date"))
```

For every unique id, I want to create a ranking. The most current date for a specific id should have a rank of 0. After, I should remove 3 months from that date (I don't consider days) to get the date of the rank -1. I have to repeat that until rank -19. After I add a new column that contains the rank.

The final output would look like that (Pay attention to the ranking of id=2) :

```
    id       date rank_year
 1:  1 2016-03-31         0
 2:  1 2015-12-31        -1
 3:  1 2015-09-30        -2
 4:  1 2015-06-30        -3
 5:  1 2015-03-31        -4
 6:  2 2016-03-31         0
 7:  2 2015-09-30        -2
 8:  2 2015-06-30        -3
 9:  2 2015-03-31        -4
10:  2 2014-12-31        -5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do (borrowing `order` from @akrun's answer):

```
DT[order(-date), rank_year := {
    z = month(date) + year(date)*12
    as.integer( (z - z[1L])/3 )
}, by=id]

    id       date rank_year
 1:  1 2016-03-31         0
 2:  1 2015-12-31        -1
 3:  1 2015-09-30        -2
 4:  1 2015-06-30        -3
 5:  1 2015-03-31        -4
 6:  2 2016-03-31         0
 7:  2 2015-09-30        -2
 8:  2 2015-06-30        -3
 9:  2 2015-03-31        -4
10:  2 2014-12-31        -5
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case, I have to add  `DT[order(id, -date)]` as suggested by @akrun. I do think your solution do the ranking based on the first date of a specific id.

Comment: I don't really understand the edit. Could you give dput for the new example along with desired output? If it's too big a departure from your original question, you could consider posting it as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
DT[order(id, -date)][, rank_year := 
          -1*c(0,cumsum(as.numeric(abs(diff(date)))))%/%90 , by = id][]
#    id       date rank_year
#1:  1 2016-03-31         0
#2:  1 2015-12-31        -1
#3:  1 2015-09-30        -2
#4:  1 2015-06-30        -3
#5:  1 2015-03-31        -4
#6:  2 2016-03-31         0
#7:  2 2015-09-30        -2
#8:  2 2015-06-30        -3
#9:  2 2015-03-31        -4
#10: 2 2014-12-31        -5
```